# Trouble with Arithmetic operations in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am trying to solve an arithmetic operation which is giving a different output in AT&T assembly program. The arithmetic operation is something like this `((i-(a+b)*(g+c))/((h*e)+(f+j)*d)`. The values are the following

```
a: .long 1
b: .long 2
c: .long 3
d: .long 1
e: .long 1
f: .long 1
g: .long 2
h: .long 2
i: .long 20
j: .long 2
```

According to my calculation the result supposed to be 1. However, I have give the full code below.

```
.data
intout: .string "Wert %d\n"

a: .long 1
b: .long 2
c: .long 3
d: .long 1
e: .long 1
f: .long 1
g: .long 2
h: .long 2
i: .long 20
j: .long 2

  .text

  .globl main

main:
  movl i, % eax
pushl % eax# i in the stack
movl a, % eax
movl b, % ebx
addl % eax, % ebx# a + b

pushl % ebx#(a + b) in the stack

movl g, % eax
movl c, % ebx
addl % eax, % ebx# g + c

popl % eax# get(a + b)
imull % ebx#(a + b) * (g + c), Result in eax
popl % ebx# get i
subl % ebx, % eax#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)]
pushl % eax#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)] in the stack

movl h, % eax
movl e, % ebx
imul % ebx#(h * e)
pushl % eax#(h * e) in the stack

movl f, % eax
movl j, % ebx
addl % eax, % ebx#(f + j)

movl d, % eax
imul % ebx#(f + j) * d

popl % eax# get(h * e)
addl % eax, % ebx#[(h * e) + (f + j) * d]

popl % eax#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)]
idivl % ebx#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)] / [(h * e) + (f + j) * d]

# Value = "Wert" in % eax given
pushl % eax
pushl $intout
call printf
addl $8, % esp

# Exit
movl $1, % eax
int $0x80
```

P.S. Please do inform me if I have made any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `subl` here calculates `%eax - %ebx`, so it's (a + b) * (g + c) - i.

```
popl % ebx# get i
subl % ebx, % eax#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)]
```

You can negate the result to make it right:

```
negl %eax
pushl % eax#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)] in the stack
```

Second, `imull` stores result in `%eax`, as you commented earlier. So in this code you calculate the result and then "forget" it:

```
movl d, % eax
imul % ebx#(f + j) * d

popl % eax# get(h * e)
```

Just change the registers you're working with. (And is it `imull`, not `imul`?)

Comment: Thanks alot... the problem was with  
`popl % ebx# get i
subl % ebx, % eax#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)]`   
what I have change here was:   
`popl % ebx# get i
subl % eax, % ebx#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)]
pushl %ebx#[i - (a + b) * (g + c)] in the stack`